# JavaScript, How to concat objects into arrays in LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am currently working on a project using geolocation.
Every 30 seconds, the current location was retrieved from GeoLocation and saved to LocalStorage.
I want to concat the stored objects into an array. How do I do this?

```
    const lastIndex = localStorage.getItem("lastIndex");
    const endLocation = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("location"+lastIndex));

    let map = [];

    for(let i = 0 ; i <= lastIndex ; i++) {
        map.concat(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("location"+i)));
        localStorage.removeItem("location"+i);
    };
```

This is my code.
[image]

In other words, I want to return a new object by putting the location object through the map array.

For example - map = [{"lng" : "37.12345", "lat" : "13.12345", "timestamp" : "12141251121212"},

{"lng" : "37.12345", "lat" : "13.12345", "timestamp" : "12141251121212"},

{"lng" : "37.12345", "lat" : "13.12345", "timestamp" : "12141251121212"}
]

But what comes out is null, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`concat` *returns* the new array, it doesn't modify the array you call it on. You aren't using that return value, so you don't see the combined result.

Also, since `concat` returns a new array each time, it's probably not a great choice for this. Just use `push`:

```
const map = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= lastIndex; ++i) {
    const key = "location" + i;
    map.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
// Use `map` here...
```

Note that you were using `JSON.stringify` where you wanted `JSON.parse`.